return back to root after starting spring boot in ubuntu
i am starting my spring boot jar as follows..
root@srv500720:~# docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway -p 8088:8080 app:latest

after this, i am able to start my spring boot application,
 INFO  [main] c.m.f.WebConfig: Application started ...

but when i enter ctrl + c or ctrl+z, my container is getting terminated.
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE            COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
543e9393a78d   app:latest   "java -jar -Dspring.…"   7 minutes ago       Exited (130) 8 seconds ago             zealous_wing

how would i return back to root after successfully starting my containers, and without container getting terminated.
Edit :-
is there any ways; we can detach in spring boot output screen? rather than starting with -d option, because i want to see the output then detach from console?
